# Need a quick solution to create individual CheckBoxFor for each enum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing this to display a "list" using `CheckBoxFor` in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyEnum, T("Pick Your Poison"))
<div>                
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Alcohol.Count; i++)
    {
        <label>
            @T(Model.Alcohol[i].Text)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Alcohol[i].Selected)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Alcohol[i].Value)
        </label>
    }
</div>
```

This is the `enum` I use (just for clarity):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Beer = 1,
    Vodka = 2,
    Rum = 3
}
```

This works. The problem is I am having a difficult time getting the `@T` to work translating each individual item dynamically. So, I need to just move on from this problem (which is not easily solvable - and not the point of this question).

What I want to do is output each item individually, so I can apply my own text to each checkbox item (and hence do a `@T("")` on each item) - which will work.

Problem is I cannot find any readily available information on the syntax in a view for `CheckBoxFor`.

I am wanting to do something like this in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyEnum, T("Pick Your Poison"))
<div>
    <label>
    @T("Beer") <!--This will work-->
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Beer) <!--Is this even right?-->
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Beer) <!--Is this even right?-->
    </label>
    <label>
    @T("Vodka")
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Vodka)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Vodka)
    </label>
    <label>
    @T("Rum")
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Rum)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Alcohol.Rum)
    </label>
    }
</div>
```

Is doing this possible? What's the proper syntax for individually listing items in the `CheckBoxFor` (all samples I see just use the `@for` loop). I just want to move on from trying to do it the first way with `@T` which is a method to translate a string.

Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to create a set of check boxes, one for each value in the enum?

Comment: Yes, the `@for` loop takes care of this, but I am having problems using my `@T` because it's dynmaically generated - the `@T` does its work before the view is constructed. I figured a way around it was to individually list out each enum/checkbox.

Comment: What is T?  Is it a custom helper?

Comment: Yes. I am not trying to confuse people, but I guess I have by explaining what `@T` does. Might have been better to just ask how can I separate this out. I cannot find proper syntax for `CheckBoxFor` in view. I just want to list each item individually without `@for` or `@foreach` loop. I do not want to loop - I want to do it manually.

Comment: I think what you might want is a custom editor template.  I will post an example in an answer momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What wound up working for me was the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyEnum, T("Pick Your Poison"))
<div>                
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Alcohol.Count; i++)
    {
     <label>
        @T("Beer")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Days[0].Selected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Days[0].Value)
    </label>
    <label>
        @T("Vodka")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Days[1].Selected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Days[1].Value)
    </label>
    <label>
        @T("Rum")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Days[2].Selected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Days[2].Value)
    </label>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you are describing I think a Custom Editor Template might be the solution you are looking for.  Editor Templates are almost like partial views that will be generated for a specific Type when the `EditorFor` helper is used.  To create a custom editor template, create a directory under the *View\Shared* folder, if it does not already exist, and call it *EditorTemplates*.  In this folder create a partial view that is named for the Type it will be bound to, for example *Boolean.cshtml* or *DateTime.cshtml*.

Below is an example of what the template might look like for your enum (*MyEnum.cshtml*):

```
@model MyEnum
@Html.LabelFor(m => m, T("Pick Your Poison"))
<div>
    <label>
        @T("Beer")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => MyEnum.Beer == Model)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => MyEnum.Beer)
    </label>
    <label>
        @T("Vodka")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => MyEnum.Vodka == Model)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => MyEnum.Vodka)
    </label>
    <label>
        @T("Rum")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => MyEnum.Rum == Model)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => MyEnum.Rum)
    </label>
</div>
```

To use the editor template you call `EditorFor` on a property of the view that is of type `MyEnum`.  For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyEnum PropX { get; set; }
}
```

then, in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropX)
```

Depending on what you are expecting to retrieve this may or may not be what you want but it may be a possible solution or step in the right direction for what you're looking for.